# JavaScript: How to retrieve the latest record from IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm writing a user script which main goal it is to track watched episodes. In the IndexedDB I have an objectStore({keyPath: 'episode', autoIncrement: true}) `watchedList` that contains objects `{episode: [the episodes id], currentTime: [episode watched till here]}`. My problem is now: How do I retrieve the latest record from `watchedList`.

I'm using [idb Promise Libary](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb) for the IndexedDB API. That are my approaches.

```
  db.get('watchedList', IDBKeyRange.lowerBound(1)).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  db.getAll('watchedList').then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  db.getAll('watchedList', null, 1).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
```

1: will log the first record (lowest id)

2: will log an array with the lowest ids first

3: will log an array with the first record

How do I sort the result?

Is it a good idea to accomplish my goal with following approach?

```
  db.getAll('watchedList').then(data => {
    console.log(data.pop());
  })
```

Comment: I don't think IndexDB provide such a thing. You will have to do it yourself. I would create another store where you save the last entered item referenced by primary key.

Comment: Thanks @NickHTTPS. I think maybe it's a good idea saving the time and creating an Index for it rather than another objectStore. You helped me getting this idea :) Thank you.

Comment: Yes that it's actually a better idea :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `openCursor` and specifying the direction parameter as `prev`

Comment: I never used Cursor before. Maybe need them later. For now creating an index with time record saved is doing well. Thanks!